# Synchronizing caches in a multithreaded program on multi-core system

Tags: multithreading, caching, operating-system, synchronization

How to ensure that the caches on different cores/processors are in sync with each other at any instant. For example:

```
Thread 1:
while(1)  {
a++;
}

Thread 2:
While(1)  {
    if(a%2 == 0)  {
    // do something
    }
}
```

In thread 2, when a is tried to be accessed, a would not reflect the latest value. Would this implementation using locks be a correct solution? :

```
Thread 1:
while(1)  {
a++;
}

Thread 2:
while(1){
    lock();
    unlock();
    if(a%2 == 0)  {
    // do something.
    }
}
```

Desired behavior is that we want the two threads to be as much synchronized as possible.

Comment: You have the common misunderstanding that memory visibility issues have something to do with memory caches. This is not true. Modern processors ensure their caches are synchronized in hardware (punch "MESI protocol" into your favorite search engine). To rephrase your question correctly, what you want to know is how to ensure value changes performed by one thread are predictably visible to other threads. In your code, for example, the main problem will likely be that compiler optimizations will result in `a++` not being a memory operation at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to synchronize `a++;` and `if(a % 2 == 0) { /* do something */ }` you should try this:

```
std::mutex mtx;

// Thread 1:
while(1)  {
    mtx.lock();
    a++;
    mtx.unlock();
}

// Thread 2:
while(1){
    mtx.lock();
    if(a%2 == 0)  {
        mtx.unlock();
        // do something.
    }
    mtx.unlock();
}
```

Locking a specific mutex every time before you want to use a specific resource, and unlocking it when you are done, ensure you that the operations on that resource are synchronized.

Comment: that would be a solution for sure, but I want to know whether there are any other ways than the conventional lock/semaphore solution to this problem? Coz after all it is not that tough a problem to need locks. In case both threads were writing to the variable, we would definitely need locks. But one thread is just doing an atomic read operation, and hence I feel locks can be avoided.